# How do I fix a "declared package does not match the expected package" error on Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I've feel like I have gone through the proper steps to fix this error, and I've looked at other questions about this in SO and other places, but for some reason I'm still having an issue.

I am trying to set up a project using the Apache JMeter source code.

As an example, the file `BeanShellAssertion.java` is in

```
~/workspace/apache-jmeter-2.9/src/components/org/apache/jmeter/assertions.
```

My source folder is `src/components`.  The package declaration in `BeanShellAssertion.java` is

```
package org.apache.jmeter.assertions;
```

Looking at it, it seems like everything is set up the way it is supposed to be.  However, the package declaration is causing an error:

```
The declared package "org.apache.jmeter.assertions" does not match the
expected package "components.org.apache.jmeter.assertions"
```

Image is below.  What exactly am I doing wrong here?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try a clean rebuild?

Comment: As per Jigar's suggestion below, I did, and that did the trick! I had tried a refresh and rebuild, but without the "clean," which is apparently the step it needed.  Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

put your `src/components/` to source path

> right click > properties > java build path > source > add folder > select `src/components`

Comment: I've already done that.  If you look at the screenshot, you can see that src/components is a source folder, and that org.apache.jmeter.assertions is supposedly a path under that folder, but Eclipse is still giving me grief.

Comment: what does refresh then clean & build say ?

Comment: That worked! I had done a refresh and then build and it didn't change anything, but adding the "clean" in there did the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Once I imported an existing maven project, I right clicked on the src folder and removed it from the build path. This fixed the error.

Comment: Thanks, This has helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the src folder fixes this error, but it leads to other problems. For example refactoring of this code does not work anymore, because it depends on the build path.
I recommend: Right-click the project -> Select Maven -> Update Project... -> (Set CheckBox:) Force Update...
This also fixed this error for me and e.g. refactoring of the code in the src directories can be done afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, what was missing was the package statement, so I added (for example):

`package CentralBCTestJK; // as the first line in my .java file`